# Trouble clicking button using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to make a basic form filler using Selenium on nike.com. I have completed most of it but I am having trouble clicking on the button to select the gender. I have attempted to use many examples of `find_element_by_xxxxx` code bit none of it has worked. Finding elements by id and xpath haven't come to much either. A typical error i get is `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element`. I am very new to coding so I could very easily have made an error, but any idea on how you guys would solve it would be much appreciated

[image: Picture of interface and element of website]

Comment: Are you using waits (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)? Many webpages have content that only shows up later in the loading process, and you can use waits to avoid trying to find elements until they've loaded.

Comment: can you show us some examples of selectors you have tried ?

Comment: the comment is too long so here's a hastebin: https://hastebin.com/xibifijoci.nginx

Comment: Just tried the `malebutton = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'd2a4a28a-cdb5-47ed-8723-df28df2c0f06')))` but no luck sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That XPATH is very long and you can simplify. 
By the looks of it , I would guess those Ids are changing every time there is a new session.

A more straightforward XPATH selector could be...

```
 "//span[text() = 'Male']"
```

- **//** specifies to search the entire document
- **span** specifies the type of element to search for
- **text()** specifies text that needs to be inside the element

(this will give you the span element but it should still work)

or

```
"//span[text() = 'Male']/parent::li//input"
```

(this will give you the actual input button)

Also , like [Ollin Boer Bohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6797302/ollin-boer-bohan) suggested, look into using waits before performing actions on your elements.

Comment: Wow, this is perfect thank you very much. Is it possible for you to explain how the first line of code you sent works? As in what each part of the code is doing to locate the element. I'm very keen to learn this and apply it elsewhere. Thanks again

Comment: @BenS. I've updated answer. You can also find some great tutorials on xpath w/ selenium (ex. https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

Comment: I'll be sure to look at that tutorial. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

@cavan answer is correct, Also you can use xpaht like this too

```
//input[@type='button']//following::span[text()='Male']
```

Here we can use following to locate the male, same you can do for female button